# Chrome 37 back button

Tags: chrome-for-android

I've tried various different Google searches on this, but can't seem to find the answer or even someone reporting the same problem.

I cannot for the life of me find the browsers back button. It's annoying enough that google decided to remove the refresh button from the address bar, but they can't seriously have completely removed the back button from the entire app could they?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I know under usual circumstances I can use the Android OS back button, however if I'm in the browser, then exit out to the home screen or switch to another app, and then reopen the browser, the back button no longer goes back in the browser - it goes back to the last activity I was in e.g. the home screen.

**NOTE:** This behaviour is not consistent. Like right now it is not happening, but a day or 2 ago, it was and I literally had no way to go back to the previous page because each time I pressed the back nav button the browser simply closed. So even if this does not always happen, I'm still puzzled as to where the browser back button has gone..and yet they leave the forward button in the menu...I almost never use the forward button.

p.s. If you too find the removal of the refresh button from the address bar ridiculous too, make sure to star the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411335) so that the devs might notice and actually revert it.

Comment: I have starred the Chromium issue (it should atleast be an option to out it back). It is odd about the issue you have with the back button after leaving Chrome. When I leave the app and go back I can use the OS back button to go to the previous webpage within the same tab. Have you opened an issue for your odd back button behavior?

Comment: @DainBinder I've currently not been able to recreate the issue reliably, so I've not created an issue about it. If I do manage to at some point I will.

Comment: The behavior is reliable for me. If I change to Chrome from another app, the back button always just goes back to the previous app, not the previous page. Very annoying.

Comment: This would be helpful for users like me also when our phone back button doesn't work. There must be some other way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they've completely removed it from the UI, so you have to use the Android back button.

Comment: Wow, then how do I go back _two_ pages in history?

Comment: @Protectorone Press it twice, or select the item you want from the **History**, which is still accessible from that menu.

Comment: What if your bank button doesn't work any more? I hate to have to use another android browser.

Answer (score 2):

Found this thread and just wanted to update it with a proper workaround. I used this on Chrome for Android ver 7.0.0. On my Note 9 and it works like a charm

Go to settings > home page

Set your homepage as `javascript:history.go(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you go to Settings -> Home page and set Homepage to `javascipt:window.location.back()` and use the home button as a back button.  Here is a picture.

[image]

It seems to work well but yes you did lose the home button.

Comment: But where is the home button…?

Comment: @Protectorone they may have removed this button in chrome also.  I am using an iPhone now as my main device.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Home button as Back in Chrome version 108, in Menu / Settings / Homepage, set the homepage to:

```
javascript:window.history.go(-1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).