# Go back in Chrome browser

Tags: chrome-for-android, navigation

New Android user here with what I considered to be a pretty basic question.

How do I go back in Chrome?

I know the "obvious" answer is to hit the back soft button, but that doesn't actually go back to the last page but rather to the last activity across your entire phone. For example if you're using an application other than chrome, and then switch to Chrome, and hit the back button it will not bring you to the the previous web page but rather to the previous application. At this point I don't know how to access to previous page.

Comment: Strange. Back button in my Chrome behaves as it should even Chrome is recently switched to. I'm using v46.0.x though, not the latest.

Comment: It appears that the problem is old and hasn't been fixed yet. [Chrome 37 back button](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/82746)

Comment: As far as I can tell, there isn't any issue filed for it? Perhaps the behavior is by design. It's not entirely clear you'd _want_ the OS back button to go back a page since the usual behavior is to back back to the last interaction, phone wide. If the behavior was changed to always go back to a prior page you'd break the back button for another set of uses.